# script to show git branch in bash no longer works on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, git, bashrc, prompt

In my 16.04 installation I put this in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
#Show git branch in commandline
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

It showed a prompt like this:

```bsh
user:~/myrepo (master) $
```

But when I do the same on 18.04 the prompt looks like this instead:

```bsh
user:~/myrepo $
```

How do I get it to work in 18.04?

```bsh
$ printf "%q\n" "$PS1" "$PROMPT_COMMAND" "$0" "$SHELL"
\\\[\\033\[01\;32m\\\]\\u:\\\[\\033\[01\;34m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\$\(parse_git_branch\)\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\ \$\ 
''
bash
/bin/bash
```

I’m using `sed (GNU sed) 4.4` and `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. This is a "fresh" installation, so there is nothing additional in `.bashrc`.

Comment: @PerlDuck Please add one or even two answers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.

I set an upstream, staged a commit and pushed it. After that it worked.

I thought that the script somehow used the `.git` folder that is generated with `git init`. Since it works on branches that does not have an upstream.

Answer (score 13):

Although you already solved the problem, I'd like to introduce the solution already shipped with git:

Together with git the file `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt` gets installed. Years ago it was in the *contrib* directory but meanwhile it made it into the official paths. The file isn't meant to be executed (in fact, it doesn't have `x` flags) but rather to be *sourced* from the `.bashrc`. It defines some functions to handle a pretty prompt, the most prominent being `__git_ps1`.

You can add the following lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
source /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt
export PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

The top of the file `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt` gives some description of what else can be done. My version says `1) Copy this file to somewhere (e.g. ~/.git-prompt.sh).` but this is not necessary (the instruction is obsolete).

You may also set some environment variables to alter the function's behaviour. I, for instance, use

```
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=yes
```

The result then looks like:

```
# clean
pduck:~/oss/rsyslog (master) $
```

or

```
# dirty
pduck:~/oss/rsyslog (master *) $
```

or

```
# something added to index
pduck:~/oss/rsyslog (master +) $
```

or

```
# in a completely fresh repo
pduck:~/oss/xxx (master #) $
```

---

Btw: The "proper" way to get the current branch is not to parse `git branch`'s output as that may change with new git versions.
`git branch` is a so-called *porcelain* command which means its output is nice and pretty but not guaranteed to stay the same with different versions. The git guys thus recommend *plumbing* tools for scripting. With *plumbing* the current branch can be determined with

```
if [ "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)" = "true" ]; then
    current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref --quiet --short HEAD || git rev-parse --short HEAD)
else
    current_branch=""
fi
```

The first assignment works if HEAD is a symbolic reference (that is: a branch or tag is checked out). If you checked out something that has no label (e.g. `git checkout HEAD^^`), then it fails and we use `git rev-parse --short HEAD` instead to show the SHA1. The `if` checks whether we are in a git working directory at all (because else the commands don't make any sense).

Comment: I made a fresh install tonight, and opted for this way instead. And it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the @PerlDuck's answer here's how you can have the old style of your prompt with colored git hints. Simply add these lines to the `.bashrc` file

```sh
source "/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt"
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=yes
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=yes
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=yes
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" " \\\$ "'
```