# __git_ps1 not found but does exist

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt, ps1

`~/.bash_aliases` where I set PS1, and is included in `~/.bashrc` (the default settings)

```
# color PS1
PS1="\[\033[01;90m\]\D{%H:%M} \[\033[01;33m\]Ubuntu\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;35m\]$(__git_ps1) \[\033[01;36m\]\$\[\033[00m\] "
```

But when I start a terminal I get error *__git_ps1: command not found*

But when I run the function manual `$ __git_ps1` in a git folder it does echo the current branch.

Also when I manually run
`$ PS1="\[\033[01;90m\]\D{%H:%M} \[\033[01;33m\]Ubuntu\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;35m\]$(__git_ps1) \[\033[01;36m\]\$\[\033[00m\] "`

the PS1 gets updated and `__git_ps1` part does get added.

I did not install it myself. I only installed git.
`sudo apt install -y git`  (git version 2.19.1)

`__git_ps1` is defined in `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt` (the file on [github](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.19.1/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L300))

```
grep __git_ps1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null
```

Only the `.bash_aliases` file shows up.
A full grep of git-sh-promt only returns binary matches

```
sudo grep 'git-sh-prompt' -nr /
```

What is wrong here?

[image: PS1 weirdness]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: Also, if you used double quotes, `$(__git_ps1)` will be evaluated when `PS1` is set, not when `PS1` is used (i.e., when the prompt is printed).

Comment: @muru I've added a more compact screenshot. I think it does my my problem more clear. The `$()` does work on other server where I've set the same ps1.

Comment: The point is that we **don't** want screenshots when normal text will do. https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/158442

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) where the `__git_ps1` function is defined. Is it even a function or is it a script? Where is it? ii) clarify where you set what. Is your `PS1` being set in `.bash_aliases`? Is your `.bash_aliases` sourced by `.bashrc` (the default in Ubuntu, but perhaps you've changed something)? iii) Also show us the output of `type __git_ps1`

Comment: @terdon I have updated my question. I can't find the definition, it's just part of git

Comment: No, it isn't part of `git`. You must be defining it somewhere. It may have been installed automatically for you, but it still needs to be sourced somewhere. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `grep __git_ps1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Yes, @terdon, `__git_ps1` _does_ come with git, in particular with the file `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`. See my answer to the related question [_script to show git branch in bash no longer works on ubuntu 18.04_](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044097/504066).

Comment: @PerlDuck oh, I guess Ubuntu have bundled it with `git`. I meant it isn't part of git itself, although as you say it seems to be part of the git package in Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: I have the `git-sh-prompt`. The function is inside. But I can't find a reference for it.

Comment: You get that `command not found` only once, right? Not for every single prompt in the terminal? I'd guess the usage of `__git_ps1` in the definition of `$PS1` comes _before_ the function gets defined (e.g. by sourcing `git-sh-prompt` or your file `~/.local/git-completion.bash` (shown in an older version of your post)).

Comment: Yes it's only once, Then it will set my PS1 to a var that does not contain the `__git_ps1`. It's very weird because I've never had this problem before. But it works... Can you add this as a answer?

Comment: Different issue, same solution: [Why is my function not re-evaluated in PS1?](https://askubuntu.com/q/651871/301745)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a de-colorized version for clarity:

```
PS1="\D{%H:%M} Ubuntu \w$(__git_ps1) \$ "
```

The double quotes tell Bash to evaluate what is between the quotes, including `$(__git_ps1)`, but `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt` hasn't been sourced yet, hence the error.

Simply change it to use single quotes, which will prevent `$(__git_ps1)` from being evaluated until the PS1 is evaluated (i.e. when the interactive shell is ready for input and shows you the prompt).

```
PS1='\D{%H:%M} Ubuntu \w$(__git_ps1) \$ '
```

Escaping the dollar sign also works, but it's harder to read:

```
PS1="\D{%H:%M} Ubuntu \w\$(__git_ps1) \$ "
```

By the way, `~/.bash_aliases` is intended for shell aliases, so it's a weird place to put your `PS1`. Personally I would put it in `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to check this source order?

Comment: @janw for source order, the closest you could get is `bash -x`, which is pretty verbose, but come to think of it, this could also help diagnose the original problem, cause it will show every command it executes during startup